# How to set background image in Java?

Tags: java, image, background, set

I am developing a simple platform game using Java using BlueJ as the IDE. Right now I have player/enemy sprites, platforms and other items in the game drawn using polygons and simple shapes. Eventually I hope to replace them with actual images.

For now I would like to know what is the simplest solution to setting an image (either URL or from local source) as the 'background' of my game window/canvas?

I would appreciate it if it isn't something long or complex as my programming skills aren't very good and I want to keep my program as simple as possible. Kindly provide example codes with comments to elaborate on their function, and also if it's in its own class, how to call on relevant methods used by it on other classes.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer will vary slightly depending on whether the application or applet is using [AWT](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/awt/) or [Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

（Basically, classes that start with `J` such as `JApplet` and `JFrame` are Swing, and `Applet` and `Frame` are AWT.)

In either case, the basic steps would be:

1. Draw or load an image into a `Image` object.
2. Draw the background image in the painting event of the `Component` you want to draw the background in.

**Step 1.** Loading the image can be either by using the [`Toolkit`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) class or by the [`ImageIO`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class.

The [`Toolkit.createImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage(java.lang.String)) method can be used to load an `Image` from a location specified in a `String`:

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("background.jpg");
```

Similarly, `ImageIO` can be used:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("background.jpg");
```

**Step 2.** The painting method for the `Component` that should get the background will need to be overridden and paint the `Image` onto the component.

For AWT, the method to override is the [`paint`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) method, and use the [`drawImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) method of the [`Graphics`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object that is handed into the `paint` method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    // Draw the previously loaded image to Component.
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    // Draw sprites, and other things.
    // ....
}
```

For Swing, the method to override is the [`paintComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) method of the [`JComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), and draw the `Image` as with what was done in AWT.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
　　　　// Draw the previously loaded image to Component.
　　　　g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

　　　　// Draw sprites, and other things.
　　　　// ....
}
```

**Simple Component Example**

Here's a `Panel` which loads an image file when instantiated, and draws that image on itself:

```
class BackgroundPanel extends Panel
{
    // The Image to store the background image in.
    Image img;
    public BackgroundPanel()
    {
        // Loads the background image and stores in img object.
        img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("background.jpg");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        // Draws the img to the BackgroundPanel.
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

For more information on painting:

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/)
- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) may be of help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some questions-

1. Where should the image concerned be located? Can you give an example sourcepath of the image as I'm unsure how it should be laid out.

Comment: 2. Say if I create a class called 'Background' using the above code, what method do I need to call upon, in my 'Game' class (which controls the view, size of the game window) from the Background class to make the background image appear? Please give an example.

Comment: Here's the code I currently use to set the background colour of my game window-  

view = new WorldView(world, width, height);   
view.setBackground(new Color(230, 245, 255));

Comment: Those are questions that concern more with design rather than actual painting of a background image. You may either want to post another question with relevant information, or seek more of a dialogue-type help from one of the forums out there.

Comment: In `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);`, the null represents an ImageObserver, doesn't it? Wouldn't `this` be a better choice?

Comment: Don't forget to invoke `super.paintXXX(g)` at the start of the painting method.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a new class that extends the `WorldView` class. I called my new class `Background`. So in this new class import all the Java packages you will need in order to override the `paintBackground` method. This should be:

```
import city.soi.platform.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
```

Next after the class name make sure that it says extends `WorldView`. Something like this:

```
public class Background extends WorldView
```

Then declare the variables game of type `Game` and an image variable of type `Image` something like this:

```
private Game game;
private Image image;
```

Then in the constructor of this class make sure the game of type `Game` is in the signature of the constructor and that in the call to `super` you will have to initialise the `WorldView`, initialise the game and initialise the image variables, something like this:

```
super(game.getCurrentLevel().getWorld(), game.getWidth(), game.getHeight());
this.game = game;
bg = (new ImageIcon("lol.png")).getImage();
```

Then you just override the `paintBackground` method in exactly the same way as you did when overriding the `paint` method in the `Player` class. Just like this:

```
public void paintBackground(Graphics2D g)
{
float x = getX();
float y = getY();
AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x,y);
g.drawImage(bg, transform, game.getView());
}
```

Now finally you have to declare a class level reference to the new class you just made in the `Game` class and initialise this in the `Game` constructor, something like this:

```
private Background image;

And in the Game constructor:
image = new Background(this);
```

Lastly all you have to do is add the background to the frame! That's the thing I'm sure we were all missing. To do that you have to do something like this after the variable `frame` has been declared:

```
frame.add(image);
```

Make sure you add this code just before `frame.pack();`.
Also make sure you use a background image that isn't too big!

Now that's it! Ive noticed that the game engines can handle JPEG and PNG image formats but could also support others. Even though this helps include a background image in your game, it is not perfect! Because once you go to the next level all your platforms and sprites are invisible and all you can see is your background image and any JLabels/Jbuttons you have included in the game.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this ;)

```
try {
  this.setContentPane(
    new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("your_file.jpeg")))));
} catch (IOException e) {};
```

Answer (score -1):

The Path is the only thing you really have to worry about if you are really new to Java. 
You need to drag your image into the main project file, and it will show up at the very bottom of the list.

Then the file path is pretty straight forward. This code goes into the constructor for the class.

```
    img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("/home/ben/workspace/CS2/Background.jpg");
```

CS2 is the name of my project, and everything before that is leading to the workspace.

Comment: The question is how to display an image as Background, not how to load an image from file.

Comment: Actually, @userunknown, how to load the image from the file was absolutely part of the problem the OP was confused about.

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
    function SetBack(dir) {
        document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundImage=dir;
    }
    SetBack('url(myniftybg.gif)');
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.