# How to center align background image in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, background-image

I wanted to add background image to my `JFrame`.
Background image means I can later add Components on the `JFrame` or `JPanel`
Although I coudn't find how to add background image to a `JFrame`,
I found out how to add background image to a `JPanel` from here:
[How to set background image in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523767/how-to-set-background-image-in-java)

This solved my problem, but now since my `JFrame` is resizable I want to keep the image in center.
The code I found uses this method

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //Draw the previously loaded image to Component.  
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);  　//Draw image
}
```

Can anyone say how to align the image to center of the `JPanel`.
As `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);` provides x=0 and y=0
Also if there is a method to add background image to a `JFrame` then I would like to know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming a suitable `image`, you can center it like this:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    int x = (this.getWidth() - image.getWidth(null)) / 2;
    int y = (this.getHeight() - image.getHeight(null)) / 2;
    g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
}
```

If you want the other components to move with the background, you can alter the graphics context's affine transform to keep the image centered, as shown in this more complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420651) that includes rotation.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.translate(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);
    g2d.translate(-image.getWidth(null) / 2, -image.getHeight(null) / 2);
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: On review, I see that the first example's cast to `Graphics2D` is not strictly required, although it is for the second.