# background image on a java gui

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set background image in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523767/how-to-set-background-image-in-java)

I am trying to put a background image on my java gui, and I can't figure out how to do it.  I've looked around and tried some code but I can't get it to work. I have the imageicon setup but I don't understand where I'm suppose to put this at.  Please help!

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and explain exactly how it didn't work for you.

Comment: You give no detail as to what library you're working with or what you've tried, how it's not working, etc. Please correct these deficiencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for an example of displaying an icon.

Then, depending on your requirement, [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) explains how you can then use the JLabel with the icon as a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Could this solve your problem? It's an explanation code which shows how you can put a background-image to a panel :) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm