# Text onto images via drag and drop in Applets

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, applet, awt

I need to show an image in a java applet, with a text element (label) to move to a point chosen by the user. Is it possible by dragging and dropping the text over the image? What methods would I need to use?

I am looking for something similar to [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/drag.shtml).

Edit: Thanks you for your useful response. The code below works fine! But how to get a text position by x,y coordinates within the image?

```
public class MouseDragTest extends JPanel {

    private static final String TITLE = "Drag me!";
    private static final int W = 640;
    private static final int H = 480;
    private Point textPt = new Point(W / 2, H / 2);
    private Point mousePt;
    Image img;

    public MouseDragTest() {
        img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("my_image.jpg");
        this.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 32));
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                mousePt = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                int dx = e.getX() - mousePt.x;
                int dy = e.getY() - mousePt.y;
                textPt.setLocation(textPt.x + dx, textPt.y + dy);
                mousePt = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(W, H);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int w2 = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(TITLE) / 2;
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawString(TITLE, textPt.x - w2, textPt.y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame(TITLE);
                f.add(new MouseDragTest());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drawImage()` in `paintComponent()` to show your invoice, like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523818/261156), and drag the text, like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5312702/261156). Another way is to use the [The Glass Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane).

Answer (score 1):

> How to get a text position by *x,y* coordinates within the image?

It sounds like you want to edit the text and location repeatedly. When you're done dragging, `textPt` will be the point at which you want to draw the text when you next load that image. You can store the details in `java.util.Preferences` and restore them when you restart.

```
private static class AnnotatedImage {
    File file;
    List<String> notes;
    List<Point> points;
}
```

As you are using `createImage()`, use `this` as the image observer when drawing.

```
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
```